# Where to find java class files created by GWT deferred binding?

Tags: gwt

If I understand these explanations http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html right the GWT compiler creates a *.java file for every class generated via GWT deferred binding. Are these files only in memory or stored in some kind of temporary work directory? Is there a way to have a look at the generated source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can give  the path for generated files  to gwt compiler with "-gen " option.

Also you can give the same option to com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode class.

[Gwt compiler options](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/gwt-compiler-options/)

Comment: Everyday learning new. Should I delete my post or what is the protocol for this on SO?

Comment: well, you can delete your answer.. I sometimes delete my answers that seems not right.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The compiler option 'gen' works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler generates javascript files, not java files. They are in your war directory, under your modules name. Each generated javascript file is optimized for different browsers in different language (if you are using internationalization module).

If you create your own classes with native javascript, you may specify which implementation should be used with certain user-agents, so deferred binding works with your custom code as well.

Comment: That was my thought to, but I thought should have a look at the link the OP listed: "Generators are classes that are invoked by the GWT compiler to generate a `Java implementation of a class` during compilation. When compiling for production mode, this generated implementation is directly translated to one of the versions of your application in JavaScript code that a client will download based on its browser environment."

Comment: To clarify, the GWT generator generates Java classes that are immediately compiled to JS then destroyed. At no point do you have access to this Java class.

Comment: You are right, It really says that in debug-mode you have Java classes but I think those are not stored anywhere.

Comment: I haven't found the right place to use the `-gen` command when debugging, but as a hack I've found that if you somehow break the generate class (add something into the .java file that won't actually compile), the debugger will halt with a path to `/tmp/...` that contains your file.  It is terrible, but it works :)